# Translating a pdf file

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, google-translate, translate

I am trying to translate a pdf file, extracting text is easy but maintaing the format of the document/file is the hard part, found no way to do this. Didn't found any javascript library yet which could help me through this, any idea of how a pdf file is translated would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try and convince your customers to send you a better file format, something closer to the original file format. But if you can't you should try to open the PDF in MS-Word. Sometimes this will give you surprisingly good results - despite the basic impossibility of the task ...

Comment: Is it easier to translate a ms-word document ? if yes, then please tell me how .

Comment: There are many tools for translators ("translation memory tools") that use MS-Word as a preferred source format (e. g.: SDL Trados, memoQ or Wordfast). They support you by dividing your text into sentences and managing and finding similar phrases for you. Of course, any other Office file format is supported, but PDF was not really meant for editing.

Comment: Above ones are commercial. Is there any open source library to do it ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.translationdomain.com/software/5-free-cat-tools-to-use-in-2019/